# Printing an image with printing package

Tags: flutter, image, printing

I installed [packages/printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) in order to print an image from flutter web

This is the code that I am calling from a regular button.

```
Future<Uint8List?> _generatePdf() async {
  try {

    final provider = await flutterImageProvider(
        NetworkImage(uri.toString()));

    final doc = pw.Document();

    doc.addPage(pw.Page(build: (pw.Context context) {
      return pw.Center(
        child: pw.Image(provider),
      ); // Center
    }));

    return doc.save();
  } catch (e) {

    print("****ERROR: $e****");
  }
}
```

The code executes without error, but no printing dialog opens. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Have you added `Printing.layoutPdf` to print the document?

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak I haven't. Where and how would I do that?

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak yes I figured it out, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually set the PdfJs library version for the web, a small script has to be added to your web/index.html file, just before . Otherwise, it is loaded automatically:

```
<script>
  var dartPdfJsVersion = "3.2.146";
</script>
```